# Measurable function on $(0,1)$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\lambda $ be lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$ , let $f \in L \ ^ 1 (\lambda)$ and define $g(x) = \int_x^1 \dfrac{f(t)}{t} dt$ for $x\in (0,1)$

I need to prove that $g \in L \ ^ 1 (\lambda)$ and $\int_0^1 g d\lambda = \int_0^1 f d\lambda$.

So, assuming $g$ is measurable I can show that $\int_0^1 g d\lambda = \int_0^1 f d\lambda$ (using Fubini) and to conclude that $g\in L \ ^ 1 (\lambda)$.

Im not sure how to justify that $g $ is indeed measurable.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You mean measurable in the 'Lebesgue $\mapsto$ Borel' sense, I assume?

Comment: Hmm, not sure i understand what you mean, i mean $\lambda$-measurable @Fimpellizieri

Comment: A function between two measurable spaces $f:(X, \Sigma_X)\longrightarrow (Y,\Sigma_Y)$ is measurable (by definition) if  $\forall S\in \Sigma_Y$ we have $f^{-1}(S)\in \Sigma_X$. The $\sigma$-algebras $\Sigma_X$ and $\Sigma_Y$ are the *measurable sets* of our measurable spaces.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri yea i know the definition, now i get what you meant, and yes i meant in the "lebesgue -Borel" sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$.
We have:

\begin{align}
\big|g(x)-g(x+\epsilon)\big|
&=\left|\int_x^{x+\epsilon}\,\frac{f(t)}t\,dt\right|\\
&\leq\int_x^{x+\epsilon}\,\left|\frac{f(t)}t\right|\,dt\\
&\leq\frac1{x}\,\int_{x}^{x+\epsilon}\,|f(t)|\,dt,
\end{align}

so that $|g(x)-g(x+\epsilon)\big|\to0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$.
Similarly, one can show that  $|g(x)-g(x-\epsilon)\big|\to0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$.
It follows that $g$ is continuous.
Can you conclude?

Comment: beat me to it, +1

Comment: Nice. and sure - continuous implies measurable .